# Library assistant

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, strings, programming-challenge, formatting

HackerRank currently has '7 days of JavaScript' going, a quick intro into the JavaScript language. Every day a couple of challenges will be made available. One of the challenges of today was this:

> **Task**
>
> Write a JavaScript program to display the status (i.e. display book name, author name and reading status) of books. You are given an object library in the code's template. It contains a list of books with the above mentioned properties. Your task is to display the following:
>
> - If the book is unread:
>
> `You still need to read '<book_name>' by <author_name>.`
>
> - If the book is read:
>
> `Already read '<book_name>' by <author_name>.`

`library` was provided, as was the empty function `displayInformation()` (and no, it is not allowed to pass `library` as an argument to the function).

The required code is as straight-forward as it gets, but I feel there's a more proper way to do the string formatting.

```
function displayInformation() {
    for (var i = 0; i < library.length; i++) {
        if (library[i].readingStatus) {
            console.log("Already read '" + library[i].title + "' by", library[i].author + ".");
        } else {
            console.log("You still need to read '" + library[i].title + "' by", library[i].author + ".");
        }
    }
} 

// provided by HackerRank
var library = [ 
    {
        title: 'Bill Gates',
        author: 'The Road Ahead',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Steve Jobs',
        author: 'Walter Isaacson',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
        author: 'Suzanne Collins',
        readingStatus: false
    }
];

displayInformation();
```

As you can see, I'm inconsistent within the `console.log()` functions and there's needless repetition. I'm also hacking my way into the library where I feel a more OO approach would look better. I think separating whatever you want to send to `console.log()` should be done by comma's whenever possible and concatenation should only be used if there's no other way.

Since I have to print the name of the book between `' '`, I picked concatenation for whenever the usual style (comma's) wouldn't work. Now it looks like a mess. Should I've switched to concatenation the moment one part of the string is using it?

Does JavaScript have something like a `string.format()` or would that make it look worse?

I'm not sure this is the idiomatic way of retrieving all the elements from the library either. Or hey, I may just be over-thinking a simple challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid repeating `console.log()`, you can use `library.reduce()` which'll output a global result, then passed to the console only once.

Regarding your other concern about efficient concatenation, you can use tagged strings.

It results in a more compact code, like this:

```js
var library = [ 
    {
        title: 'Bill Gates',
        author: 'The Road Ahead',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Steve Jobs',
        author: 'Walter Isaacson',
        readingStatus: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games',
        author: 'Suzanne Collins',
        readingStatus: false
    }
];

function displayInformation() {
  console.log(library.reduce( (output, book) => output +=
    `${book.readingStatus ? 'Already read' : 'You still need to read'} ${book.title} by ${book.author}.\n`, ''
  ));
}

displayInformation();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to skin this particular cat:

- ES6: Use template strings: something like `'Hello, ' + place + '!'` turns into `` `Hello, ${place}!` ``
- Concatenate later:

```
var statusPrefix = library[i].readingStatus
    ? "Already"
    : "You still need to";
console.log(statusPrefix + ' read ' + library[i].title + "' by", library[i].author + '.');
```

It's better to define what `library[i]` is, or you can use `forEach`:

```
function printBookStatus(book){
    var statusPrefix = book.readingStatus
        ? "Already"
        : "You still need to";
    console.log(`${statusPrefix} read "${book.title}" by ${book.author}.`);
}

library.forEach(printBookStatus);
```